# PHP: Fatal error: Class 'Cal\Sitemap\Helper\SitemapHelper' not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I created a little helper which should help me to create a sitemap.

This is the declaration of the helper:

```
<?php

namespace Cal\Sitemap\Helper;


/**
 * Class SitemapHelper
 * @package Cal\Sitemap\Helper
 */
class SitemapHelper
{
...
```

And this is how I want to use it:

```
<?php

use Cal\Sitemap\Helper\SitemapHelper as Sitemap;

...

    $test = new Sitemap;
```

But unfortunately I'm getting this:

> FatalThrowableError in SitemapController.php line 27: Fatal error:
>   Class 'Cal\Sitemap\Helper\SitemapHelper' not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do have included the class defining script somehow?

Comment: Also you have an error in the object creation the right way is new Sitemap();

Comment: @Dan Ionescu If there are no parameters `()` arent needed, so no error.

Comment: Did you use an `autoloader` or do you incldue the class files?

Comment: Hello,

I I'm using Pagekit. There I define the following in the index.php:

 
 'autoload' => [
  'Cal\\Sitemap\\' => 'src'
 ],